# VLC interface problem in 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, vlc

In VLC if I enter into full screen mode by double clicking, then after auto screen turn off time(The time of inactivity after which the screen turns off in idle mode) the mouse pointer and the control panel disappears and I can't exit full screen mode by double clicking. I have to do it by right clicking and selecting full screen mode and then unselecting it. The mouse pointer still remains invisible in the video playback area. Also menus appear in an extra bar under the windows title bar after exiting full screen every time(Even if I exit full screen by double clicking). And also exiting full screen mode always presents a "not maximized" VLC window. How to solve these VLC interface problems?

Comment: it's bugging me too.

Comment: Double menu bar issue is related to qt apps, i installed smplayer (qt based) it behaves the same - double menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Ubuntu 18.04

Just added PPA to system and worked fine for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```